# Extract dates from /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, users, shadow

The file `/etc/shadow` has a couple date fields that are expressed as the  number of days since Jan 1, 1970.  Is there an easy way using to get a list of users and the calendar date of the last password change, and the expiration?

Ref: [man shadow(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an answer that got deleted, while somewhat wrong, did lead me in the correct direction.

Using gawk's [strftime](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) combined with some arithmetic gives me what I wanted.

```
cat shadow | gawk -F: '{ print $1 ":" strftime("%Y%m%d",86400*$3) ":" strftime("%Y%m%d",86400*$4)}'

root:20120304:19691231
daemon:20100203:19691231
bin:20100203:19691231
sys:20100203:19691231
```

Comment: be nice and don't gawk at the cat



gawk -F: '{ print $1 ":" strftime("%Y%m%d",86400*$3) ":" strftime("%Y%m%d",86400*$4)}' /etc/shadow

Comment: @ChrisAlderson Meh, the UUOC people won't convince me.  I find the `cat file | filter | filter` more readable, and sometimes when I am being lazy I will do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
chage -l <username>
```

Example Output:

```
Last password change                                    : Dec 17, 2015
Password expires                                        : Mar 16, 2016
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 7
Maximum number of days between password change          : 90
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 14
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for n in $(sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk '{FS=":";print $3}'); do date -d "01/01/1970 +${n}days" +%F; done
```

To avoid the useless-use-of-cat-award:

```
for n in $(sudo awk '{FS=":";print $3}' /etc/shadow); do date -d "01/01/1970 +${n}days" +%F; done
```

Answer (score 3):

report password status on the named account `passwd -S username`

`for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do sudo passwd -S $user; done`

Comment: +1 That would works, but not in my particular case.   I am gathering information for all users, from a copy of the shadow restored to a temp folder from the backup, I was trying to track down some password changes to see if they are related to a system being potentially compromised.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs password update information for each user:

*Read the /etc/passwd file >> parse each user >> run chage -l command on each user*

```
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do echo -e "\n $user \n" && chage -l $user; done
```

Answer (score 0):

"... the calendar date of the last password change":

```
19139
$ date -d '01 Jan 1970 19139 days'
27.05.2022
```

19139 from /etc/shadow

One can use all above in a loop.